# Adding XML mappings to Spring Boot project

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to add the XML Hibernate/JPA mappings to a Spring Boot project. Where should I put it and what should I name it?

I tried putting it in src/main/resources/orm.xml and that didn't work.

For the record, my orm.xml looks like this:

```
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">
    <mapped-superclass class="tech.dashman.common.models.PersistedModel"/>
    <mapped-superclass class="tech.dashman.common.models.User"/>
    <mapped-superclass class="tech.dashman.common.models.Account"/>
</entity-mappings>
```

then in my project I have a User and an Account class that inherit those classes and use the Java annotations:

```
@Entity(name = "accounts")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Account extends tech.dashman.common.models.Account {
}

@Entity(name = "users")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class User extends tech.dashman.common.models.User {
}
```